# Gerador de classe automático

Tags: c#, oracle

Como eu faço para pegar no BD(Oracle) uma entidade e gerar no meu sistema uma classe que represente aquela entidade?

Ex: Tenho essa entidade

> Cliente
>
> ID int primary key
>
> Nome varchar(100)

E agora com a ferramenta ela já gera isso:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace meu_projeto.meu_folder.classes
{
public class Cliente{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

  }
}
```

Ou seja, gerar uma classe POCO tendo por base uma entidade do BD(Oracle), como eu faço?

Estou usando WPF para isso.

Comment: O que você já tentou? Digo, só tem a ideia? Não sabe nem por onde começar?

Comment: Não fiz nada ainda. Estou na fase da pesquisa na web, entre elas o SOpt, que para mim, é a primeira pesquisa que faço. Mas estou no momento, pesquisando também em outras fontes, mas acredito muito no SOpt. No momento, só tenho a idéia e o pedido do gestor.

Comment: Meus 20 cents: procure sobre *reflection*

Comment: Ok, vou começa a pesquisar desde agora. Vou te dar um voto no comentário, valendo 20 cents, ehehe.

Comment: O que eu preciso no momento, é ler o banco e trazer os campos de uma tabela. A questão toda é como identificar uma coleção`(FK N => 1 ou 1 => N ou N => N, aí uma associação no meio)`.

Comment: Se você vai usar um ORM, geralmente ele já tem função para gerar entidades a partir da estrutura da base de dados. Por exemplo, para gerar entidades usando Entity Framework: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs

Comment: Tá osso fazer um gerador. Ainda não consegui um meio de pegar os fields e types de uma tabela e gerar a poco.

Comment: Utilize o entity framework com a abordagem database first. Aqui está um link explicando como faz: https://csharp.today/entity-framework-6-database-first-with-oracle/

Comment: Para obter nomes e tipos de colunas de uma tabela no Oracle: `select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'NOME_TABELA'`. Qual a dificuldade específica para gerar o POCO?

Comment: Cara, a um tempo atrás eu fiz uma consulta sql para montar a classe, só que ela só funciona pra SQL Server.

Comment: Você pode usar o Entity Framework Code First from Database para isso, ele irá gerar todas as Classes POCO a partir do seu DB. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Com a versão *core* do *Entity Farmework* é possível utilizar a linha de comando direto no *Package Manager Console*

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Sendo necessário ter os seguintes pacotes:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
```

No entando esse exemplo é para Sql Server, mas acredito que para Oracle seria somente utilizar os Providers disponibilizados pela Oracle